# Jhipster Registry With OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, okta, jhipster-registry

I am using Jhipster Registry v5.0.2. With JWT security everything is working. Other application is also working with full functionality. No Issue with JWT.

When I am trying to use OAuth 2.0 its giving problem. Jhipster Registry is starting up. able to login also. for registry able to check health and all.

But the issue with Registered client. Both are using same OAuth credential. Metrics and Swagger API is not working. Its able to get the swagger docs. its generating the swagger page correctly.

But once I go to test it always say unauthorized. I observed its generate Header --header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: ' look like this is blank.

When I tried the accessing the service through postman directly passing Authorization header its worked.

I tried both Okta and Keyloak. both have same issue.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can be this a problem with CORS ? (Cross Origin Requests ? )

Comment: I don't think so. complete administration tab item doesn't work with OAuth. I am trying to figure it out. look like its not able to set Authorization header. backend code is generating token and its valid. but its not saved for Swagger UI header. initOAuth is never get called. and its missing oauth information.